# UDP TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, udp, client-server

I'm completely newbie to python and computer networking. While working on Uni project I have faced a problem. What am I doing wrong? Any help will me much appreciated.

Here is server side:

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    print ("Server Started.")
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        print ("message from: ") + str(addr)
        print ("from connected user: ") + str(data.decode('utf-8'))
        data = str(data).upper()
        print ("sending: ") + str(data)
        s.sendto(data, addr)

    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Here is my client side:

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    server = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    message = input('->')
    while message != 'q':
        s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        print ('Received from server: ') + str(data)
        message = input('->')
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__' : 
    Main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of issues; mostly with the printing.

You had a few instances of `print('some text') + str(data)`; this won't work, because while `print()` outputs to the screen (STDOUT) it returns `None`, so what you were actually doing was trying to concatenate `None + str(data)`

What you need is `print('some text' + str(data))`.

Additionally, there was as issue on the server-side where you echo the data received from the client back to the client- it needed to be re-encoded as a bytearray (it comes in as a bytearray, gets converted to a utf-8 string for display, it needs to go back to bytearray before replying).

In summary, server:

```
import socket


def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    print("Server Started.")
    while True:
        try:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            print("message from: " + str(addr))  # moved string concatenation inside print method
            print("from connected user: " + str(data.decode('utf-8')))  # moved string concatenation inside print method
            data = str(data).upper()
            print("sending: " + str(data))  # moved string concatenation inside print method
            s.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), addr)  # needed to re-encode data into bytearray before sending
        except KeyboardInterrupt:  # added for clean CTRL + C exiting
            print('Quitting')
            break

    s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

And the client:

```
import socket


def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5001

    server = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    message = input('->')
    while message != 'q':
        try:
            s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            print('Received from server: ' + str(data))  # moved string concatenation inside print method
            message = input('->')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:  # added for clean CTRL + C exiting
            print('Quitting')
            break

    s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Thank you Edward so much. And this one on client side: print('Received from server: ' + str(data.decode('utf-8')))?

Comment: Good pickup- yes, you'll need that on the client side. It might be easier to convert data as required after receiving it, then you don't have to work with it every time you use it. E.g.: `data = data.decode('utf-8')`, then you can use data as a string (which it will be).